# How to use laravel 5 and sqlserver on linux platform?

Tags: php, sql-server, linux, laravel, laravel-5

I have always been developing on linux mint using laravel 5 and mysql. This time around, the company is using sqlserver 2012. I have edited my .env file as follows:

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv
DB_HOST=server@domain.com
DB_DATABASE=hidden
DB_USERNAME=hidden
DB_PASSWORD=hidden
```

When I execute `artisan migrate`. I get the error `[PDOException] could not find driver`

I research the web and found out that there is some `php_pdo_sqlserv.dll` and `php_sqlsrv.dll` available for windows users. How can I install these dlls on XAMPP linux and continue my app development. Appreciate help. Has someone faced this problem before? How did you solve it.

**Additional Info**

`phpinfo` shows that pdo_mysql, pdo_pgsql and pdo_sqlite are all insalled. I have the following files in my linux box.

```
/etc/odbcinst.ini
/etc/odbc.ini
/opt/lampp/etc/freetds.conf
```

Comment: Could this be usefull for you? http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php

Comment: Which version of php you are using? @FokwaBest

Comment: Hi @PassionInfinite, my xampp for linux come with PHP Version 5.6.3

Comment: so i'm using PHP Version 5.6.3

Comment: Any help will much appreciated

Comment: Just install the mysql driver package in ubuntu using sudo apt-get install php5.6-mysql and then restart server then you are good to go! @FokwaBest

Comment: Hi @PassionInfinite. I'm not using mysql in this case. I want to connect to a sql server database

Comment: Did you change/add the driver details in database.php file? @FokwaBest

Comment: Nope. Laravel already has this ' 'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver'   => 'sqlsrv',
            'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'  => 'utf8',
            'prefix'   => '',
        ],'

Comment: I simply specify my connection info in .env.

Answer (score 1):

After [the basics](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/database#configuration), just install **php-sybase**:

```
sudo apt install php7.1-sybase
```

Then try again :)

**UPDATE:** Now there is a [full documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/microsoft-php-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) for that

Comment: not working on php7.2 
 php7.2-sybase : Depends: libsybdb5 (>= 0.63) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: Now there is a full documentation for that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/microsoft-php-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Yeah thanks I finally solved, I noticed that PECL was installing the sqlsrv.so and pdo_sqlsrv.so in a folder that was for another PHP version... I passed a suffix for PECL with my actual PHP version and worked

Answer (score 0):

You can use Laravel + PHP 7 + Ubuntu 16.04 with SQL Server

```
sudo apt-get -y install php7.0 libapache2-mod-php7.0 mcrypt php7.0-mcrypt php-mbstring php-pear php7.0-dev apache2
sudo su
sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://apt-mo.trafficmanager.net/repos/mssql-ubuntu-xenial-release/ xenial main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssqlpreview.list'
apt-key adv --keyserver apt-mo.trafficmanager.net --recv-keys 417A0893
apt-get install msodbcsql unixodbc-dev-utf16
pecl install sqlsrv-4.0.7 pdo_sqlsrv-4.0.7
echo "extension=/usr/lib/php/20151012/sqlsrv.so" >> /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini
echo "extension=/usr/lib/php/20151012/pdo_sqlsrv.so" >> /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini
echo "extension=/usr/lib/php/20151012/sqlsrv.so" >> /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
echo "extension=/usr/lib/php/20151012/pdo_sqlsrv.so" >> /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
wget "https://aka.ms/laravel.tar.gz"
tar -xzf laravel.tar.gz
cd laravel
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
composer install
```

Edit the database.php file in the /larvel/config folder using your favorite text editor with the settings below. Don't forget to update the username and password with your own. Save and close the file.

```
'sqlsrv' => [
        'driver'   => 'sqlsrv',
        'host'     => 'localhost',
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'SampleDB'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'sa'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'your_password'),
        'prefix'   => '',
]
```

Run a migration. This will use the Laravel ORM (Eloquent) to create the required tables and schema for the app.

```
php artisan migrate
php artisan serve
```